# Show ajax form resuslts in page

Tags: custom-post-types, custom-taxonomy, ajax, forms

I have [this](http://formazione-salesforce.enigen.it/prova-2/) multi-steps form which should filter through user's choices and give back a list of posts, related to that choices. I'm trying to do that with ajax, but even if I get the response in ajax that response does not output in the page.

**JS**

```
  $(".submit").click(function(e) {

    var form = $('#msform');
    var url = ajax_object.ajax_url;
    var fdata = {};
    fdata['action'] = 'process_form';
    fdata['prodotto'] = form.find('input[name="prodotto"]').val();
    fdata['livello'] = form.find('input[name="livello"]').val();
    fdata['ruolo'] = form.find('input[name="ruolo"]').val();
    fdata['stato'] = form.find('input[name="stato"]').val();

    $.ajax({
           type: "POST",
           url: url,
           data: fdata,
           success: function(resp)
           {
               var res_tab = $("#res-tab");

               res_tab.empty();
               res_tab.append(resp.data);

               $("fieldset").hide();
               res_tab.show();
           },
           error: function(error) {
               console.log(error);
           },
        });

        e.preventDefault(); 
    });
```

**FUNCTIONS.PHP** ||*Edit: relation 'AND' added to tax query*

```
 function enqueue_radio() {
        if (is_page_template('modello-2.php')){ 
  wp_enqueue_script( 'radio', get_stylesheet_directory_uri() . '/js/radio.js', array('jquery'), '', false );
          wp_localize_script( 'radio', 'ajax_object', array('ajax_url' => admin_url('admin-ajax.php')) );
               }
             }
            add_action( 'wp_enqueue_scripts', 'enqueue_radio' );



function process_form() { 

global $wpdb;
$prodotto = $_POST["prodotto"];       
$livello = $_POST["livello"];       
$ruolo = $_POST["ruolo"];       
$stato = $_POST["stato"]; 
?>
 <div id="res-tab" class="row">
<?php

    $args = array( 
                'post_type' => 'corsi',
                'posts_per_page' => -1,
                'orderby' => 'title',
                'order'   => 'ASC',
                'tax_query' => array(
                        array(
                            'taxonomy' => 'prodotto',
                            'field' => 'name',
                            'terms' => $prodotto,  
                            'relation' => 'AND',
                            ),
                        array(
                            'taxonomy' => 'livello',
                            'field' => 'name',
                            'terms' => $livello,
                            'relation' => 'AND',
                            ),
                        array(
                            'taxonomy' => 'ruolo',
                            'field' => 'name',
                            'terms' => $ruolo,
                            'relation' => 'AND',
                            ),
                        array(
                            'taxonomy' => 'stato',
                            'field' => 'name',
                            'terms' => $stato,
                            'relation' => 'AND',
                            ),        
                        ) 
                    );
    $soluzioni = new WP_Query($args);
        if ( $soluzioni->have_posts() ) {
            while ( $soluzioni->have_posts() ) {
            $soluzioni->the_post(); ?>

    <div class="col-md-6 largo">
        <div class="blocco">
            <h3 style="font-size:20px;line-height:23px;"><?php the_title();?><br/>
            <?php  
            $codice = get_post_meta($post->ID, '_corsi_codice', true);
            echo '( '.$codice .' )'; ?></h3>
            <p>
                <?php the_content();?>
            </p>
            <div class="dettagli row">
                <div class="col-md-6 no-pads">
                    <h5>PRODOTTO</h5>
                    <p>
                        <?php echo get_the_term_list( $post->ID, 'prodotto', '',', ', '' ); ?>
                    </p>
                    <h5>AUDIENCE</h5>
                    <p>
                        <?php echo get_the_term_list( $post->ID, 'ruolo',  '',', ', ''); ?>
                    </p>
                </div>
                <div class="col-md-6 no-pads">
                    <h5>MODALITà DI EROGAZIONE</h5>
                    <p>
                        <?php  $modalita = get_post_meta($post->ID, '_corsi_modalita', true);
            echo $modalita; ?>
                    </p>
                    <h5>DURATA</h5>
                    <p>
                        <?php  $durata = get_post_meta($post->ID, '_corsi_durata', true);
            echo $durata; ?>
                    </p>
                </div>
                <a href="<?php echo the_permalink()?>">
                    <button>DETTAGLI</button>
                </a>
            </div>

        </div>
    </div>
    <?php   } 

    wp_reset_postdata(); } 
    else {
            echo '<br/>NO POST FOUND';
        }

?>
</div>

<?php         

   wp_send_json_success( $soluzioni);   

    wp_die();
 }

 add_action( 'wp_ajax_nopriv_process_form', 'process_form' );
```

**And, the template page for the form**

```
<div id="res-cont" class="container">
                <div id="bloccoton" class="row sw-main sw-theme-arrows">
                    <ul id="progressbar" class="nav nav-tabs step-anchor">
                        <li class="nav-item done"><a href="#step-1" class="nav-link">Cloud di interesse</a></li>
                        <li class="nav-item"><a href="#step-2" class="nav-link">Livello di esperienza sulla piattaforma</a></li>
                        <li class="nav-item"><a href="#step-3" class="nav-link">Ruolo nell'utilizzo di Salesforce</a></li>
                        <li class="nav-item"><a href="#step-4" class="nav-link">Modalità di eorgazione del corso</a></li>
                        <li class="nav-item"><a href="#step-5" class="nav-link">Corsi</a></li>
                    </ul>
                    <div class="intro">
                        Stai già utilizzando uno dei prodotti di Salesforce? O lo farai nel prossimo futuro? Diventa un esperto di Salesforce, scegli di specializzarti nel tuo Cloud di riferimento e costruisci il tuo percorso di crescita all’interno dell’azienda.
                    </div>
                    <div class="col-md-3">
                        <div id="corsi-res">
                            <div class="filtro">
                                <p style="font-weight:bold; text-align:center;padding:25px 0;">My Training</p>
                                <div class="scelt-con prod">

                                    <p id="prodotto"></p>
                                    <input type="button" id="uno" class="del" name="del" value="X">
                                </div>
                                <div class="scelt-con liv">
                                    <p id="livello"></p>
                                    <input type="button" id="due" class="del" name="del" value="X">
                                </div>
                                <div class="scelt-con role">
                                    <p id="ruolo"></p>
                                    <input type="button" id="tre" class="del" name="del" value="X">
                                </div>
                                <div class="scelt-con sta">
                                    <p id="stato"></p>
                                    <input type="button" id="tre" class="del" name="del" value="X">
                                </div>
                            </div>


                        </div>

                    </div>
                    <div class="col-md-9">
                        <form id="msform" method="post">
                            <!-- progressbar -->

                            <!-- fieldsets -->
                            <fieldset class="con-img">
                                <h2 class="fs-title">PRODOTTO DI RIFERIMENTO</h2>


                                <?php

    $prodotto_terms = get_terms( 'prodotto', array(
          'orderby'    => 'date',
          'order' => 'DESC',
          'hide_empty' => 0
        ) );
    ?>
                                    <?php foreach( $prodotto_terms as $term ) {
                          $term_link = get_term_link( $term );
                          echo '<label class="table-disp">';
                             if ($term->slug === 'service-cloud') {
                            echo '<img class="iconza" src="'.get_stylesheet_directory_uri().'/img/Service-cloud.png">';
                            } elseif ($term->slug === 'platform') {
                            echo '<img class="iconza" src="'.get_stylesheet_directory_uri().'/img/Platform.png">';
                             }
                                 elseif  ($term->slug === 'marketing-cloud-pardot') {
                            echo '<img class="iconza" src="'.get_stylesheet_directory_uri().'/img/Marketing-cloud.png">';
                             }
                            elseif ($term->slug === 'einstein-analytics') {
                            echo '<img class="iconza" src="'.get_stylesheet_directory_uri().'/img/Einstein.png">';
                             }
                            elseif ($term->slug === 'community-cloud') {
                            echo '<img class="iconza" src="'.get_stylesheet_directory_uri().'/img/Community-cloud.png">';
                             }
                            elseif ($term->slug === 'sales-cloud') {
                            echo '<img class="iconza" src="'.get_stylesheet_directory_uri().'/img/Sales-cloud.png">';
                             }


                          echo '<input type="radio" name="prodotto" class="smoothie" value="'.$term->name.'"><span>'.$term->name.'<br><span style="font-weight:400">'.$term->description.'</span></span></label><br>';


                        }       

                    ?>
                                        <input type="button" name="next" class="next action-button" value=">" />
                            </fieldset>
                            <fieldset>
                                <h2 class="fs-title">IMPOSTA IL TUO LIVELLO DI PARTENZA</h2>

                                <?php $livello_terms = get_terms( 'livello', array(
          'orderby'    => 'date',
          'order' => 'DESC',
          'hide_empty' => 0
        ) );
    ?>
                                    <?php foreach( $livello_terms as $term ) {
                          $term_link = get_term_link( $term );
                          echo '<label class="table-disp"><input  type="radio" name="livello" class="smoothie" value="'.$term->name.'"><span>'.$term->name.'</span></label><br>';
                        }       

                    ?>
                                        <input type="button" name="previous" class="previous action-button" value="<" />
                                        <input type="button" name="next" class="next action-button" value=">" />
                            </fieldset>
                            <fieldset>
                                <h2 class="fs-title">QUALE MANSIONE RICOPRI NELL’UTILIZZO DEL CRM?</h2>

                                <?php $livello_terms = get_terms( 'ruolo', array(
          'orderby'    => 'date',
          'order' => 'DESC',
          'hide_empty' => 0
        ) );
    ?>
                                    <?php foreach( $livello_terms as $term ) {
                          $term_link = get_term_link( $term );
                          echo '<label class="table-disp"><input type="radio" name="ruolo" class="smoothie" value="'.$term->name.'"><span>'.$term->name.'</span></label><br>';
                        }       

                    ?>
                                        <input type="button" name="previous" class="previous action-button" value="<" />
                                        <input type="button" name="next" class="next action-button" value=">" />
                            </fieldset>
                            <fieldset class="con-img">
                                <h2 class="fs-title">COMPLETA FLESSIBILITÀ NELLE MODALITÀ DI EROGAZIONE </h2>

                                <?php $livello_terms = get_terms( 'stato', array(
          'orderby'    => 'date',
          'order' => 'DESC',
          'hide_empty' => 0
        ) );
    ?>
                                    <?php foreach( $livello_terms as $term ) {
                          $term_link = get_term_link( $term );
                                echo '<label class="table-disp">';
                             if ($term->slug === 'privato') {
                            echo '<img class="iconza" src="'.get_stylesheet_directory_uri().'/img/Salesforce-private-training.png">';
                            } elseif ($term->slug === 'pubblico') {
                            echo '<img class="iconza" src="'.get_stylesheet_directory_uri().'/img/Salesforce-public-training.png">';
                             }

                          echo '<input type="radio" name="stato"  class="smoothie" value="'.$term->name.'"><span>FORMAZIONE STANDARD - '.$term->name.'<br><span style="font-weight:400">'.$term->description.'</span></span></label><br>';
                        }       

                    ?>
                                        <label class="table-disp"><img class="iconza" src="<?php echo get_stylesheet_directory_uri()?>/img/Enigen-workshop.png">
                                        </label><br/>
                                        <label class="table-disp"><img class="iconza" src="<?php echo get_stylesheet_directory_uri()?>/img/Salesforce-user-adoption.png"><span>CORSI USER ADOPTION<br>
                                        </label>

                                        <input type="button" name="previous" class="previous action-button" value="<" />

                                        <input type="button" name="submit" class="submit action-button" value=">" />
                            </fieldset>
                        </form>


                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="container">

            </div>


            <?php get_sidebar();?>
            <?php get_footer();
```

Comment: I notice you only hook into the logged out version of the AJAX request, but have you considered instead using a REST API? Afterall you're already dealing with JSON. The REST API endpoint would have told you point blank what the problem was instead of returning an empty response. Additionally, your taxonomy query has multiple terms but no qualifier, is it A and B and C or A or B or C etc

Comment: It would be an A and B and C, etc. I'll correct the query, thanks. As per the REST API, to be honest, I don't know how to use them :/

Comment: You should ask on the site! It's actually much easier than it sounds